# k-means iterative output of data+centroid

Tags: octave, matlab, matlab-figure

I've got a question regarding the `kmeans` function in Matlab.
I want to do a plot with multiple plots of various steps, which shows the evolution/movement of cluster centers and the labelling of the cluster data.
Asked a friend of mine who already played around with the k-means function, but he said that wouldn't be possible.
Is he right or is it possible to plot the data of the input vector and the centroids via iteration?
If it's possible, how is it realized?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: The matlab documentation for kmeans() gives an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) of how to make a plot where each point is colored according to its cluster, and the cluster centers are plotted as well. You can update that plot every iteration to visualize what's happening.

Comment: mh, nope... as far as I am understanding the example it plots only the final respectively the best iteration in it's final step of the k-means. What I need and what I'd mentioned is the progression/iterative moving of the centroid. If I am calling the k-means method I only get the final result of the error minimization / minimal distance function.

Comment: Try `kmeans()` with `MaxIter=1`. Call it and show plot in a loop, feeding output from previous call as input for the next. I don't know if it'll work or what side effects it might entail, so first you may want to compare single call result with result of the loop.

Comment: or open the  kmeans .m file and add what you need as an output variable .